# How to make custom node set includes some nodes in trees package on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

Please tell me how to make custom node set which consist of some nodes using `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle`.

In the below code, I want to set `node` of line (1)-(3) into a custom node set by `\tikzset`. On the Tikz tree package, the problem is that it is difficult to set together node commands into `\tikzset`. Because the nodes are described in different locations. For example, line (2) is 4 line far from line (3).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
grow via three points={one child at (0.6,-0.7) % 
    and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-0.5)},%
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {Root}
  child {
  node (child1){Child1} % (1)
  child { node {Child2}
      child { node {Child3}
    }
    }
  node[right=3mm of child1,draw=orange]{msglabel!} %(2)
  node[right=24mm of child1,draw=purple]{msglabel2!} % (3)
};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can do this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, positioning}

\newcommand{\foobar}[3]{#1 #3 #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw=black, thick, anchor=west},
  grow via three points={one child at (0.6,-0.7)
                         and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-0.5)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
  ]
  \node {Root}
    child {
      \foobar
        { node (child1) {Child1} } % (1)
        {
          node[right=3mm of child1, draw=orange]{msglabel!}   %(2)
          node[right=24mm of child1, draw=purple]{msglabel2!} % (3)
        }
        {
          child
            {
              node {Child2}
                child { node {Child3} }
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\tikzstyle` is obsolete, better use `\tikzset` instead, as in:

```latex
\tikzset{
  every node/.style={draw=black, thick, anchor=west},
}
```

But since this particular setting is rather invasive, I prefer doing it in the options of the `tikzpicture` where it is needed. This way, it doesn't affect other `tikzpicture` environments of the same document (see the above example).

Comment: Thank you very much, frougon!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer). :-)

Comment: My reputation count is less than 15, so could not vote, sorry.

Comment: @user2058374 Right, but you can accept (making the check mark become green). This is different from upvoting. Only the asker can accept, and this can be done regardless of the number of “reputation” points (this will even give you... 2 points, I believe). Thanks.

Comment: I got it, I did that to have marked green a checkmark.

Comment: @user2058374 Yep, that's it, thank you. :-)